# How can I combine my Spring Backend Filter with Ng2SearchPipeModule

Tags: angular, spring, ionic-framework

I have a question. In the frontend I have installed a `NG2SearchPipeModule` filter which also works, but since I have several thousand data, I decided to solve the filter via a NameQuery in the backend.

In the backend I have two methods:

1. `getAllCarGroupNamesWithId` to get all records.
2. `findByCarNameAndExternalId` with the built-in filter query (see below).

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% OR d.carName LIKE %:carNameAndExternalId% ")
    List<CarLocationEntityView> findByCarNameAndExternalId(String carNameAndExternalId);
```

As interface I use OpenApi 3.0
In the frontend I added the interfaces in a service class so that I can work with both methods.

The list to be filtered calls the method getAllCarGroupNamesWithId when the page is loaded and returns all elements. So far so good.

In my Ionic app I built a Ng2SearchPipeModule filter including a `searchbar` that filters this list with all data in the frontend. However, I want to make sure that the list is already filtered in the backend with my findByCarNameAndExternalId method to increase the performance of the application. But I don't have the idea how to do that, that when entering e.g.
BM (for BMW ) a request can be sent to the backend.

```
<ion-col size="12">
            <ion-list id="list" lines="inset">
              <ion-item id="list-item" button *ngFor="let carGroup of carGroups | orderBycarGroupName | filter: searchTerm
              | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: cp}"  class="listMargin" (click)="openCarGroup(carGroup.id)">
                <ion-label>{{carGroup.id}}</ion-label>
                <ion-label>{{carGroup.carGroupName}}</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
```

Does anyone have a solution that I can work with?

Comment: `I want to make sure that the list is already filtered in the backend` What does it mean? What is the search flow? Do you want to sort the search results as per the string provided by user?

Comment: For example, if I use Ng2SearchPipeModule in the FrontEnd to enter something into the SearchBar (e.g. a mer) then all possible records containing mer are immediately displayed. But there could be thousands of records that have to be reloaded all the time. I want that when entering mer my filter that I have implemented in the backend starts and sends only the required data to the frontend. I hope I have understood your question correctly

Comment: So the way should be: I enter something in the search bar and the entered value is sent as parameter via Openapi to the backend. This parameter is sent to the method findByCarNameAndExternalId and this method filters all possible records and returns them to the frontend.